# What is "output_projection" parameter in tensorflow seq2seq models

Tags: python, tensorflow

For a LSTM (RNN) cell.

It has three vectors coming out of it:

1. Output vector of size = batch_size * decoder_vocab
2. Cell_state of size = batch_size * Embedding(=size of each LSTM cell)
3. Hidden state of size = same as Cell_state

To further confirm: When we use seq2seq it gives two outputs

```
outputs, state = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq(...)
```

output is 1.st variable mentioned above and state contains 2.nd and 3.rd vectors mentioned above.

Now while testing/ predicting, we can directly pass output value to the next decoder input, but due to the space issue, as [mentioned here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq#sampled_softmax_and_output_projection) , we use output_projection (W,B).

Now my doubt is to which vector/ value do we mutiply out_projection with (W * ? + B), to reduce the space, and how does it reduce the space.